# Qml - Why the data of the delegate in the tableview will not be deleted when the model is deleted

Tags: qt, qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Button {
        text:"add"
        onClicked: {
            listmodel.append({"StartTime":"","EndTime":""})
        }
    }
    Button {
        text:"delete"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        onClicked: {
            tableview.selection.forEach(function(rowIndex){
                listmodel.remove(rowIndex)
            })
        }
    }
    TableView {
        id:tableview
        width: 640
        height: 450
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        selectionMode: SelectionMode.SingleSelection
        rowDelegate:Rectangle {
            color: styleData.selected?"blue":"white"
            height: 50
        }

        model: ListModel{
            id:listmodel
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role:"StartTime"
            width: 300
            delegate: TextField{
                text: styleData.value
                onActiveFocusChanged: {
                    if(!activeFocus)
                        text = "2010-09-03"
                }
            }
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role:"EndTime"
            width: 300
            delegate: TextField{
                text: styleData.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first step is to add a row to the Tableview, then automatically fill in the data in the first column, then select the first row to delete, and then add a new row, the data in the first column still exists.

The version of Qt is 5.9.6MSVC2015 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick check resulted in the following finding:

TableView seems to recycle once created delegates. This means, they are not deleted but kept around for further use. When they are reused, they will just change the exposed data `styleData` and thereby update the bindings.

To prove that the objects are not destroyed when you remove the model entry, change the delegate to this:

```
delegate: TextField{
    text: styleData.value
    onActiveFocusChanged: { if(!activeFocus) text = "2010-09-03" }
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(this, "has been created")
    Component.onDestruction: console.log(this, "will be destroyed")
}
```

Since you break the binding to the model data with the line:

```
onActiveFocusChanged: { if(!activeFocus) text = "2010-09-03" }
```

in the reused Item that value won't be updated again.

~~~ That much for the *why* things are.

What can you do? Well, the obvious thing is, to not break the binding.
The easiest would be to change the value in the model instead of setting the text:

```
onActiveFocusChanged: { if(!activeFocus) model.startTime = "2010-09-03" }
```

But this might be unwanted?

---

Reading through the code of `TableView`, I found two interesting comments:

- [`// Used as a cache for rowDelegates`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml#n412)
- [`// We recycle instantiated row items to speed up list scrolling`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml#n517)

which may explain the intention behind this *feature*.

Comment: yeah,you are right,I have tried your code,In other words,  must write like this:                    `if(!activeFocus)listmodel.setProperty(styleData.row,"StartTime","2010-09-03")`，but if i want to break the binding,what should i do?

Comment: @bai, if you don't start your role names with capital letters, it is also possible to directly set `model.startTime = "2010-09-03`

Comment: To quote from the documentation of `ListModel`: *"Roles (properties) in each element must begin with a lower-case letter and should be common to all elements in a model. The ListElement documentation provides more guidelines for how elements should be defined."* - the only way to circumvent this, is by using the JS syntax you were using, but that is... maybe not that nice? :D

Comment: I also haven't caught destroying the delegate. Probably there is some cache bufer or something like that.

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan: In the code we find the comment [*// Used as a cache for rowDelegates*](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml#n412) - and [*// We recycle instantiated row items to speed up list scrolling*](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml#n517)

Answer (score -1):

Because `tableview` are not updating automaticaly when you are changing `listmodel`.

It'll work:

```
Button {
    text:"remove"
    anchors.right: parent.right
    onClicked: {
        tableview.selection.forEach(function(rowIndex){
            listmodel.remove(rowIndex)
        })
        tableview.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that it's problem of TableView, because with ListView I didn't have such problems. And it's obvious that view must track model changes and updates itself. Of course, probably, with C++ model (which implements QAbstractItemModel) this problem is not actual as well.

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan: It doesn't seem to be related to track model changes. The data that is shown does not come from the model. `onActiveFocusChanged: { if(!activeFocus) text = "2010-09-03" }` breaks the binding. The value is not put into the `ListModel`. To me it seems like the created delegates are recycled by just setting a new styleData context, and trying to update the bindings. But since the binding has been broken, the `text` will stay. I will later dig into the code to verify this thesis. (Or maybe someone else can?)

Comment: For me this leads to the console output `TableView_QMLTYPE_41 : Update called for a item without content` - but no resolution to the problem.

Comment: @derM I've tested the author's code and can say the following - I connected to Component.onCompleted and Component.onDestruction and the delegate haven't been destructed. I can't get why.

Comment: @derM - the same for me. provided solution doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for inappropriate answer, guys. Somehow it worked for me. 
Qt 5.9.2